# Conversion of Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a comparison on the basis of CreatedDate but it gives me an error like

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

here is my query as @startdate and @endDate are my parameters for the Stored procedure.

```
declare @startDate as varchar(100) = null
declare @endDate as varchar(100) = null
set @startDate = '01/11/2016'
set @endDate = '30/11/2016'

SELECT CreatedDate FROM Table1 
WHERE HCCreatedDate BETWEEN 
CONVERT(Datetime, ISNULL(@startDate,''), 103)
    AND CONVERT(Datetime, ISNULL(@endDate,''), 103)
```

Comment: Check your HCCreatedDate column datatype.Is it varchar or datetime datatype.Without select CreatedDate from Table1 where HCCreatedDate this query.There is no error

Comment: i think so for this date '30/11/2016' it is taking 30 as month and not date

Comment: Use proper data types. Never store dates as varchar.

Comment: please show some sample dates in the table and the data type of HCCreatedDate

Comment: It's best to get used to the format "yyyy-mm-dd" in SQL and use correct date formats (not varchar)

Comment: ohhh  sorry HCCreatedDate  is same as CreatedDate and its data type is varbinary as this is encrypted column.

Comment: You need to convert HCCreatedDate to Datetime also then you can compare

Comment: @AksheyBhat yeah thats working. thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: @RichBenner For what it is worth, `yyyy-MM-dd` is still ambiguous for the `DATETIME` data type in SQL Server.  This will throw an error for example: `SET DATEFORMAT DMY; SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-30')`. The only culture invariant format for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` types is `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just declare your variables with the correct type in the first place? There is zero benefit to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please convert the HCCreatedDate column as below

```
declare @startDate as varchar(100) = null
declare @endDate as varchar(100) = null
set @startDate = '01/11/2016'
set @endDate = '30/11/2016'

SELECT 
    CreatedDate 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,HCCreatedDate,103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(@startDate,''), 103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(@endDate,''), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Conver your column into Datetime. and try again

```
declare @startDate as varchar(100) = null
declare @endDate as varchar(100) = null
set @startDate = '01/11/2016'
set @endDate = '30/11/2016'

SELECT CreatedDate FROM Table1 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, HCCreatedDate), 103)BETWEEN 
CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(@startDate,''), 103)
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(@endDate,''), 103)
```